# Submartingale convergence

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

> Let $(X_n)_n$
> be a submartingale such that $M=\sup_n E [X^+ _n
> ] < ∞$ where $X^+ _n = max(0, X_n)$.
> Prove:
> there exist a random variable $X_∞ ∈ L^1 (Ω, P)$ such that $X_n → X_∞$ almost surly as $n → ∞$.
> Hint: Use the Doob-Meyer decomposition and martingale convergence theorem.

I didn't use the hint and want to ask if you think my answer is correct. Also I'm wondering what is the solution using the hint.

$$ X_n \leq E[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]$$
$$ E[|X_n|]=E[X_n ^+]+E[X_n ^- ]$$
If $N=\inf_n \{-E[X_n ^-]\} =-\infty$ then we get
$$ E[X_0] \leq E[X_{n}]\rightarrow -\infty$$ contradiction because $E[X_0]$ is finite

Now $E[|X_n|]<M+|N|$ and so from $L^1$ martingale we get the convergence to $X_\infty \in L^1$

Comment: Why is $EX_n^{-} \leq N$?  The inequality is in the other direction.

Comment: I fixed it. $N=inf -E[X_n ^-] = sup E[X_n ^-]$ so $EX_n ^- \leq N$

Comment: it should be =-[_ ^-] and so $EX_n ^- \leq |N|$

Answer (score 1):

Doob decomposition: $X_n=M_n+V_n$ with $(M_n)$ a martingale and $(V_n)$  increasing, predictable (i.e. $V_n$ is $\mathcal F_{n-1}$ measurable for $n\ge 1$), and $V_0=0$.

1. Show that $E|M_n| = 2E\left[M_n^+\right] -E[M_0]$.
2. Notice that $M_n^+\le X_n^+$ for $n\ge 0$.
3. Use 1., 2., and the basic hypothesis to enable use of martingale convergence theorem.
4. What does 3. tell you about $\lim_n X_n$?